# TransformerFactory in BlackBerry?

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me, sax, xml-parsing

How do I use TransformerFactory in BlackBerry for XML creation?

Java has TransformerFactory method. But BalackBerry does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since BlackBerry uses J2ME as their software platform, you are somewhat limited in the third-party Java libraries you can use in your project.  You may want to take a look at something like [Javolution](http://javolution.org/)
 or other libraries which are specifically targeted for J2ME.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting xerces.jar/xalan.jar into your device. Then you can use Xalan's native api to do XML Transformations.

See http://xalan.apache.org/

I can't guarantee that xalan would actually work on BlackBerry, tho.

Comment: Hi 
Alamar,Thanks for your reply.
The above appraoach did not work for me 
:(

Please help me for implementation of TransformerFactory in BlackBerry.

Thanks .

Comment: "did not work" is useless.
What did you try. What have you got?